# Invalid column name $JACOCODATA using ant jacoco and junit

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit, jacoco

I am using jacoco for generating my test cases report. But while building the project I am getting the error as :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar *my sql query* nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name $JACOCODATA.
```

It is automatically adding this Jacoco column to my query but it isn't there in my query.. why is it happening?

When I tried it using emma this was being replaced by `$VRC`.. thus the same error..

Answer (score 3):

Jacoco weaves an additional field named $jacocoData into the inspected classes, this probably causes the error you describe

Answer (score 0):

f.isSynthetic()
It can solve your confusion。

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).